# Remove tuple from a list if both elements are partial string match based on regex

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
[('B5A', 'B5B'), ('B5A', 'B5'), ('B5A', 'B28A'), ('B5A', 'B28B'), ('B5A', 'B28C'), ('B5A', 'B28D'), ('B5A', 'B28E'), ('B5A', 'B28F'), ('B5A', 'B28G'), ('B5A', 'B28H'), ('B5A', 'B28'), ('B5B', 'B28A'), ('B5B', 'B28B'), ('B5B', 'B28C'), ('B5B', 'B28D'), ('B5B', 'B28E'), ('B5B', 'B28F'), ('B5B', 'B28G'), ('B5B', 'B28H'), ('B5B', 'B28'), ('B5', 'B28A'), ('B5', 'B28B'), ('B5', 'B28C'), ('B5', 'B28D'), ('B5', 'B28E'), ('B5', 'B28F'), ('B5', 'B28G'), ('B5', 'B28H'), ('B5', 'B28'), ('B28A', 'B28B'), ('B28A', 'B28C'), ('B28A', 'B28D'), ('B28A', 'B28E'), ('B28A', 'B28F'), ('B28A', 'B28G'), ('B28A', 'B28H'), ('B28A', 'B28'), ('B28B', 'B28C'), ('B28B', 'B28D'), ('B28B', 'B28E'), ('B28B', 'B28F'), ('B28B', 'B28G'), ('B28B', 'B28H'), ('B28B', 'B28'), ('B28C', 'B28D'), ('B28C', 'B28E'), ('B28C', 'B28F'), ('B28C', 'B28G'), ('B28C', 'B28H'), ('B28C', 'B28'), ('B28D', 'B28E'), ('B28D', 'B28F'), ('B28D', 'B28G'), ('B28D', 'B28H'), ('B28D', 'B28'), ('B28E', 'B28F'), ('B28E', 'B28G'), ('B28E', 'B28H'), ('B28E', 'B28'), ('B28F', 'B28G'), ('B28F', 'B28H'), ('B28F', 'B28'), ('B28G', 'B28H'), ('B28G', 'B28'), ('B28H', 'B28')]
```

I have a list of tuples as above and I want to remove all the tuples from this list if it's elements are partial match for example fist letter B and number after B is same then remove the tuple. so the output should be

```
[('B5A', 'B28A'), ('B5A', 'B28B'), ('B5A', 'B28C'), ('B5A', 'B28D'), ('B5A', 'B28E'), ('B5A', 'B28F'), ('B5A', 'B28G'), ('B5A', 'B28H'), ('B5A', 'B28'), ('B5B', 'B5'), ('B5B', 'B28A'), ('B5B', 'B28B'), ('B5B', 'B28C'), ('B5B', 'B28D'), ('B5B', 'B28E'), ('B5B', 'B28F'), ('B5B', 'B28G'), ('B5B', 'B28H'), ('B5B', 'B28'), ('B5', 'B28A'), ('B5', 'B28B'), ('B5', 'B28C'), ('B5', 'B28D'), ('B5', 'B28E'), ('B5', 'B28F'), ('B5', 'B28G'), ('B5', 'B28H'), ('B5', 'B28')]
```

Comment: You have put ('B5B', 'B5') in the result but its should not be, as you have described the algorithm this is a partail match.

Comment: That's correct it shouldn't be, I have edited ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [i for i in lst if re.findall(r'B\d+',i[0]) != re.findall(r'B\d+',i[1])]
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explaination to your answer. Only code answers are considered as moderatly helpful, which can be improved.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a simple list comprehension:

```py
lst = [('B5A', 'B5B'), ('B5A', 'B5'), ('B5A', 'B28A'), ('B5A', 'B28B'), ('B5A', 'B28C'), ('B5A', 'B28D'), ('B5A', 'B28E'), ('B5A', 'B28F'), ('B5A', 'B28G'), ('B5A', 'B28H'), ('B5A', 'B28'), ('B5B', 'B5'), ('B5B', 'B28A'), ('B5B', 'B28B'), ('B5B', 'B28C'), ('B5B', 'B28D'), ('B5B', 'B28E'), ('B5B', 'B28F'), ('B5B', 'B28G'), ('B5B', 'B28H'), ('B5B', 'B28'), ('B5', 'B28A'), ('B5', 'B28B'), ('B5', 'B28C'), ('B5', 'B28D'), ('B5', 'B28E'), ('B5', 'B28F'), ('B5', 'B28G'), ('B5', 'B28H'), ('B5', 'B28'), ('B28A', 'B28B'), ('B28A', 'B28C'), ('B28A', 'B28D'), ('B28A', 'B28E'), ('B28A', 'B28F'), ('B28A', 'B28G'), ('B28A', 'B28H'), ('B28A', 'B28'), ('B28B', 'B28C'), ('B28B', 'B28D'), ('B28B', 'B28E'), ('B28B', 'B28F'), ('B28B', 'B28G'), ('B28B', 'B28H'), ('B28B', 'B28'), ('B28C', 'B28D'), ('B28C', 'B28E'), ('B28C', 'B28F'), ('B28C', 'B28G'), ('B28C', 'B28H'), ('B28C', 'B28'), ('B28D', 'B28E'), ('B28D', 'B28F'), ('B28D', 'B28G'), ('B28D', 'B28H'), ('B28D', 'B28'), ('B28E', 'B28F'), ('B28E', 'B28G'), ('B28E', 'B28H'), ('B28E', 'B28'), ('B28F', 'B28G'), ('B28F', 'B28H'), ('B28F', 'B28'), ('B28G', 'B28H'), ('B28G', 'B28'), ('B28H', 'B28')]

lst = [i for i in lst if i[0][:2] != i[1][:2]]
```

Comment: This will not work if I have list like [('B2','B28'),(('B2A','B28')] in this case your above suggestion will not work. you code will only work if both entry don't start with same comb. I am looking for a general code that suggest if number after B is same then remove that tuple